# Dominated convergence for sequences with two parameters, i.e. of the form $f_{m,n}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_{m,n}(x)$ be a sequence (dependent on $m$, $n$) of Lebesgue integrable functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that $f_{m,n}(x)\to 0$ as $m,n\to+\infty$, for almost $x\in\mathbb{R}$; in addition, $\left|f_{m,n}(x)\right|\le g(x)$ for all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Can we apply the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem to conclude that $\int_\mathbb{R} {{f_{m,n}}\left( x \right)dx}  \to 0$ as $m,n\to+\infty$?

(Here notice that $a_{m,n}\to 0$ iff for all $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$: $\forall m,n\ge N\Longrightarrow|a_{m,n}|<\varepsilon$).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can note that you can see $\{f_{n, m}\} $ as a single index sequence. Or you can check that the proof of the dominated convergence theorem applies to your situation.

Comment: I do not know more when you said that you can see $f_{n,m}$ as a single index sequence. Can you explain in more detail for me?

Comment: The only reason why the statement of the DCT does not apply directly to your situation is that you have a doubly indexed sequence.  But it is still a sequence, so the theorem does apply.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\int f_{m,n}$ does not converge to $0$. Then there are sequences 
$m_k$, $n_k$ tending to infinity such that $\int f_{n_k,m_k}$ does not converge to $0$. Now apply Lebesgue to the single index sequence $g_k=f_{n_k,m_k}$ and obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Yes. I understood your answer. Thank you very much.